# Who should I send my thank you letter to?

Tags: interviewing, email

I just interviewed with a company in person, and I know I need to send a thank you email.  At the interview, I met with about 8 people.  These people included a person from HR, the director of the branch for the company I'm applying, and other people from all levels.

Do I send my thank you letter to each person individually?  Or do I pic and choose?  Or should I email them all with one email? Or perhaps I should do something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I send my thank you letter to each person individually? Or do I pic
>   and choose? Or should I email them all with one email? Or perhaps I
>   should do something else?

Yes, send your thanks to everyone you met.

Use customized individual letters (or customized individual emails, if you prefer).

The point of a thank you letter is usually to get yourself a bit more attention from the hiring company. Thanking everyone individually gives you a chance to highlight something discussed with that individual, and hopefully make an even better impression.

Think of something, some special connection, that you can convey to each individual separately. Show them that you are willing to put some effort into things, rather than just tossing off a "Thanks" email and copying everyone. A good job is worth some effort.

You never know which individual might put in a good word that is the tipping point leading to your hire - thank them all, and make it feel personal.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - it's really helpful.  I forgot to mention that I spoke to two people at a time for some of the interview.  My gut says to email them both in a single email because my thanks applies to them both equally.  Is that a good idea?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that then.  Thanks again for the advice!  huge help

Comment: I will say most of the time we get a thank you note to the group at most.  If individual notes were sent it would help a candidate stand out.

Comment: BTW i did end up getting an offer after this interview, and I accepted it.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What if I can't remember every detail I shared with one person?